# Android ADT and SDK compatability issues

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse(juno) from SDK bundle windows-x86_64-20130729. I updated my adt version 22.0.5 to 23.0.6.1720515 but when I try to set the SDK location I am getting error;
this android sdk requires adt version 22.6.2 or above.Current version is 22.0.5.please update adt.
When i try to update adt to 23.0.6.1720515 it gives error;
cannot complete request .adt will be ignored because it is already installed.
Suggestions please?

Comment: Restart eclipse... ?Try it.

Comment: Why not use Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Google is not giving update to the Eclipse it is recommended that you should use the ***Android Studio***. 
But still you want to go with Eclipse than you can remove your existing bundle and download new bundle. from below link - It has new version of eclipse

**windows 32**: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

**windows 64:** https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip